# Maven Compilation Error - Package does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, package

I have a multi-module project in IntelliJ with the following structure:

```
**simulator**
    pom.xml
**protocol** -> has dependency on simulator
    pom.xml
```

Everything is resolved fine in the code editor, in my **protocol** project I can import package from **simulator** and build the protocol project without problems.

The problem starts when I try to use Maven - if I run the "package" command, I get a lot of errors regarding packages not existing. Please see screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

My **protocol** project pom.xml has a dependency on the **simulator** project, like so:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.pervasive_intelligence.simulator</groupId>
            <artifactId>simulator</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The scope is set to "Compile". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may consider creating a parent pom.xml file that will define the dependencies between your modules and import/build it instead of 2 individual pom files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a single parent pom.xml file solved the problem.